# Creating a rank column after UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-rank

I'm attempting to create a `SalesRank` column based on the amount in column `SalesAmount`.

I'm attempting to do something similar to this: `RANK() OVER(Order BY SalesAmount desc) as StateRank`, but I am unsure on how to execute this after joining two tables together? How can I create another column after the union of both tables? In order to do this will I need to insert my union select into a `#temptable`?

Here is an example of my table:

| StateId | ReportTitle | ReportId | SalesAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Online Sales in California | 21 | 21512 |
| 12 | Online Sales in New York | 37 | 13201 |
| 14 | Online Sales in Michigan | 91 | 9212 |
| 23 | Online Sales in Nevada | 14 | 12931 |
| 8 | Online Sales in Pennsylvania | 14 | 23413 |
| 13 | Online Sales in Oregon | 14 | 9651 |

I am expecting to have a return like:

| StateId | ReportTitle | ReportId | SalesAmount | SalesRank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Online Sales in California | 21 | 21512 | 2 |
| 12 | Online Sales in New York | 37 | 13201 | 3 |
| 14 | Online Sales in Michigan | 91 | 9212 | 6 |
| 23 | Online Sales in Nevada | 14 | 12931 | 4 |
| 8 | Online Sales in Pennsylvania | 14 | 23413 | 1 |
| 13 | Online Sales in Oregon | 14 | 9651 | 5 |

Here is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE TableOne
(
    StateId INT,
    ReportTitle VARCHAR(100),
    ReportId INT,
    SalesAmount Money, 
)

INSERT INTO TableOne (StateId,ReportTitle,ReportId,SalesAmount)
VALUES (1,'Online Sales in California',21, 21512),(12,'Online Sales in New York',37,13201), (14,'Online Sales in Michigan',91,9212)

CREATE TABLE TableTwo
(
    StateId INT,
    ReportTitle VARCHAR(100),
    ReportId INT,
    SalesAmount Money, 
)

INSERT INTO TableTwo (StateId,ReportTitle,ReportId,SalesAmount)
VALUES (23,'Online Sales in Nevada',14,12931), (8,'Online Sales in Pennsylvania',14,23413), (13,'Online Sales in Oregon',14,9651)

SELECT * FROM TableOne 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM TableTwo
```

Comment: Yes, you use SELECT INTO a temp table and then rank your results or just use a CTE. I'd recommend trying a CTE first, if performance is slow, then use a temp table

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term CTE. Could you please provide an example if possible?

Comment: CTE = Common Table Expression. It's kind of like a temporary view. Microsoft doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.

```
SELECT  *
        ,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SalesAmount DESC) AS RowRank
FROM    (
            SELECT  *
            FROM    TableOne
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  *
            FROM    TableTwo
        ) AS t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (which in this case is just a neater/different way to write a sub-query, but does provide more benefits in other situations).

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM TableOne
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *
  FROM TableTwo
)
SELECT *
     , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SalesAmount DESC) AS RowRank
FROM cte;
```